# Не вызывается метод didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, ios

Мне нужно отслеживать выделение элементов UITableView в обоих режимах. Но метод didSelectRowAtIndexPath не вызывается в editing mode (редактирование таблицы). Как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это поможет:

```
tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```